# project euler project 4: largest palindrome product

Tags: java

I am trying to solve Project Euler Problem 4 (A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers) but am receiving an error with my code, which is as follows:

```
public static boolean palindrome(String pal, int length){
    int i;//counter for charAt starting at 1
    int x=length;//counter for charAt starting at length of product
    int count=0;//counter to check if product actually is palnidrome
    for (i=1;i<=length;i++){
        if (pal.charAt(i)==pal.charAt(x)){
            count++;
            x--;
        }
    }
    if (count==length){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x;//number one
    int y;//number two
    int z;//product of both numbers
    int largest=0;//largest number
    int length;//length of product
    String product;//product of both numbers as string
    boolean check;//variable to determine whether product is palindrome
    for (x=100;x<=999;x++){
        for (y=100;y<=999;y++){
            z=x*y;
            product=String.valueOf(z);
            length=product.length();
            check=palindrome(product,length);
            if (check==true){
                largest=z;
            }
            System.out.println(largest);
        }
    }
}
```

but am getting the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
    at pkg4.largestpalindromeproduct.LargestPalindromeProduct.palindrome(LargestPalindromeProduct.java:24)
    at pkg4.largestpalindromeproduct.LargestPalindromeProduct.main(LargestPalindromeProduct.java:48)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

the weird thing is, when i change x to equal "length-1", the code runs fine, but that then starts with the second to last digit rather than the last one, so I keep getting 0 as my answer. Please help me fix it. Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: this breaks at the very first run through, by the way, to get a product of 10000 (100*100) so x should be 5, since 10000 has 5 digits, not 4.

Answer (score 1):

There are two hard problems in computer science: caching, naming variables, and off-by-one errors.

```
    for (i=1;i<=length;i++){
```

Everything in Java is 0-indexed.

Comment: +1 for "There are two hard problems in computer science: caching, naming variables, and off-by-one errors."  LOL

Comment: what do i do to fix it?

Comment: @Sal well, how do you get the 1st character of a String?

Comment: product.charAt(0); yeah, I realized that that was the issue, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the answer, though I am not sure why this was the issue. In my for loop in my palindrome function, I had it as i<=length. What fixed it was changing it to (i < length). I am not sure why this is so, so could someone please enlighten me and tell me why this was happening? Thanks a lot.

Comment: String eg = "12345" , eg.length = 5 , eg.charAt(0) = 1 , eg.charAt(4) = 5  and finally eg.charAt(5) = error java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. because there is no character at index 5

you get the same error when your i <= length, when i enters the loop for last time its value is 5 then the system checks 5 <=5 which is true then it proceeds to perform the action charAt(5) and that is when you get the error.

Comment: there are two solutions either you put i<=length-1 or i<length depending on what actions you want to perform with i inside the loop.